# Error: Argument tensors passed to stack must be a `Tensor[]` or `TensorLike[]`

Tags: lstm, tensorflow.js

Could you please specify where in the code the error occurs? Additionally, could you identify the line number where this error is thrown? It would be helpful to understand the expected behavior of the code and what it's supposed to do. Are there any relevant error stack traces or additional error details that could provide more information about the issue? Have you thoroughly checked the data loaded from the JSON file to ensure it matches the expected format for model training? These details will be essential in diagnosing and resolving the error in your code.

I got the error Error: Argument tensors passed to stack must be a `Tensor[]` or `TensorLike[]` in my following code:

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
const fs = require('fs');

// Fungsi untuk memuat dan memproses data
async function loadData() {
    const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data/dataset.json', 'utf-8'));
    // Konversi data ke tensor dan praproses data di sini
    // Misalnya, ekstrak data AQI dan komponen polutan
    const inputs = [];
    const labels = [];

    for (let record of data.list) {
        inputs.push([
            record.components.co,
            record.components.no,
            record.components.no2,
            record.components.o3,
            record.components.so2,
            record.components.pm2_5,
            record.components.pm10,
            record.components.nh3
        ]);
        labels.push(record.main.aqi);
    }

    // Konversi ke tensor
    const inputTensor = tf.tensor2d(inputs);
    const labelTensor = tf.tensor2d(labels, [labels.length, 1]);
    const reshapedInputTensor = inputTensor.reshape([inputTensor.shape[0], 1, inputTensor.shape[1]]);

    // Split data menjadi set pelatihan dan pengujian
    const splitIdx = Math.floor(reshapedInputTensor.shape[0] * 0.8);
    const [trainInput, testInput] = tf.split(reshapedInputTensor, [splitIdx, reshapedInputTensor.shape[0] - splitIdx]);
    const [trainLabel, testLabel] = tf.split(labelTensor, [splitIdx, labels.length - splitIdx]);

    return {trainData: {xs: trainInput, ys: trainLabel}, testData: {xs: testInput, ys: testLabel}};
}

// Fungsi untuk membuat model LSTM
function createModel(inputShape) {
    const model = tf.sequential();

    // Layer LSTM pertama dengan returnSequences = true
    model.add(tf.layers.lstm({
        units: 50,
        returnSequences: true,
        inputShape: inputShape
    }));
    model.add(tf.layers.dropout(0.2));

    // Layer LSTM kedua tanpa repeatVector
    model.add(tf.layers.lstm({units: 50}));
    model.add(tf.layers.dropout(0.2));

    // Layer dense untuk output
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1}));

    model.compile({
        optimizer: 'adam',
        loss: 'meanSquaredError',
        metrics: ['accuracy']
    });

    return model;
}


// Fungsi untuk melatih model
async function trainModel(model, trainData, testData) {
    const history = await model.fit(trainData.xs, trainData.ys, {
        epochs: 50,
        validationData: [testData.xs, testData.ys],
        verbose: 1
    });
    return history;
}

// Fungsi untuk menyimpan model
async function saveModel(model) {
    await model.save('file://path_to_save_model');
}

// Fungsi utama
async function run() {
    const {trainData, testData} = await loadData();
    const model = createModel(trainData.xs.shape.slice(1));
    await trainModel(model, trainData, testData);
    await saveModel(model);
    console.log('Model training complete and model saved.');
}

run()
```

my dataset:

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": 106.8272,
        "lat": -6.1754
    },
    "list": [        {
            "main": {
                "aqi": 3
            },
            "components": {
                "co": 413.9,
                "no": 0.07,
                "no2": 3.04,
                "o3": 105.86,
                "so2": 3.73,
                "pm2_5": 17.24,
                "pm10": 49.92,
                "nh3": 3.1
            },
            "dt": 1701842400
        }
    ]
}
```

I hope the code can run LSTM training to predict AQI values